# How to toggle between two jQuery functions for Introjs tour plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, intro.js

I am in the process of learning jQuery and JS, so I apologize if this is a stupid, easy question.

I am working with a tour plugin called intro.js that adds hints to a web page (bootstrap page). I got the intro.js hints working, however I need to be able to show and hide all of the hints by toggling one button. The way the plugin currently works, you show the hints by clicking a button, then you have to manually click on each hint icon to view the tooltip, then click a button on the tooltip to hide the hint icon. The web pages could have several hints displayed (anywhere from 10-15) and users may not want to see what all hints are, as they may want to just see what 1 or 2 are then close all the hints - so I want to be able to toggle all of them on/off with one button.

According to the plugin API (view it here: https://introjs.com/docs/hints/api/), the hints are added when the button is clicked using this function: introJs.addHints(). You are supposed to be able to hide all of the hints using this function: introJs.hideHints().

So, how can I toggle both of these functions with one button?

Also, another issue I am having is if a user does not close all of the hint icons and they open a new page, the hint icons are still visible. If I refresh the page, they disappear. Related to this, if someone opens the hints and closes them, but decides to reopen the hints again, they do not open unless the page is refreshed. The API documentation has a function called: introJs.refresh() that says it refreshes and rearranges the hints. I think this is what I need to clear the existing hints (but I could be wrong). How can I clear/refresh the hints when the hints are closed so users can reopen the hints if needed, without refreshing - and so the hints disappear if a new page is opened and some hints were not closed.

Please help me with these questions and make a newbie's Christmas/holiday even better!!!

Here is a jsfiddle with hints added to a bootstrap modal. The Show Hints link is what I need to toggle on/off: http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/fc0rkakn/

Thank you to everyone reading - and Happy Holidays to all of you.

Sample HTML:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a href="#notesModal" data-toggle="modal" role="dialog" id="btnOpenModal" class="btn btn-primary">Open Notes Modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="notesModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="notesModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Notes</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="note-input" data-hint="Input your notes here." data-hintposition="top-middle" data-position="bottom-right-aligned">
               <input type="text" name="note" class="col-md-11" maxlength="300"/><button id="add-note" data-hint="Select Add button to save and add your notes." data-hintposition="top-middle" data-position="bottom-right-aligned">Add</button>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="note-total" data-hint="Track your remaining characters here." data-hintposition="top-middle" data-position="middle-right" style="margin-left:15px;">0/300
      </div>          
      <div><a class="btn btn-tour" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:introJs().addHints();"><i class="fa fa-bus"></i>&nbsp;Show Hints</a></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The API allows introJs to be commanded and for callbacks to be attached to various internal events, however it doesn't provide for inspection of state (in particular whether or not a hint is currently showing).

To achieve the toggle function, you will need to manage a state variable of your own.

Something like this ...

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var hintShowing = false; // a variable by which to track the state of introJs.

    introJs("#targetElment");

    $("#myToggleButton").on('click', function() {
        if(hintShowing) {
            introJs.hideHints();
            hintShowing = false;
        } else {
            introJs.showHints();
            hintShowing = true;
        }
    });

    function setShowing() {
        hintShowing = true;
    }
    function resetShowing() {
        hintShowing = false;
    }

    introJs.onchange(setShowing).oncomplete(resetShowing).onexit(resetShowing);

    // add hints and set options here
});
```

That should work, at least to a certain extent. It depends on whether `onchange` fires when the initial hint is shown. If not, `setShowing()` will also need to be called manually (from your own code when the hint sequence starts) or maybe just initialise `var hintShowing = true;`

Comment: Thank you Roamer for your reply. I tried applying your code, but I keep getting a syntax error (missing ; before statement). I added a link to a jsfiddle I used to add the hints to bootstrap modal. Can you show me how to get this working on the jsfiddle?

Comment: First, track down the syntax error. The message should included a line number. It'll be something simple. I'm on my phone right now so can't do much.

Comment: Roamer, question - what is the introJs("#targetElement"); for? Is this supposed to be the element (id or class) that I am applying the hints to? If yes, there will be several different elements with hints.

Comment: @Rex, I've never actually used `introJS`, only studied the documentation. As I understand it, your HTML must contains directives in the form of attributes such as `data-intro` and `data-step:`, then everything is initialised in javascript with an expression of the general form `introJs()` or `introJs(selector);`. You probably know more about this aspect than I do so please ignore me if I've got it wrong.